# Understanding EvaluationData in messages context

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages, message-coding

Can I `Quiet` my procedure and still get messages info from inner `EvaluationData`?

This works fine:

```
EvaluationData[1/0]["MessagesExpressions"]
```

> ```
> {Hold[Message[Power::infy, 1/0]]}
> ```

but I don't want to propagate messages up so I use `Quiet`:

```
Quiet @ EvaluationData[1/0]["MessagesExpressions"]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

I didn't expect that since `Quiet` is outer to `EvaluationData`.

It seems inconsistent with respect to `Check` behavior:

```
Quiet @ Check[1/0, err]
```

> ```
> err
> ```

Here inner messages are captured correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

The definition of [`EvaluationData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationData.html) can be read with `PrintDefinitions` from the GeneralUtilites package, wherein we see:

```
handleMessage = logMessage[$messages, #1] &;
Internal`AddHandler["Message", handleMessage];
```

The definition of `logMessage` includes:

```
CloudObject`Private`logMessage[bag_, Hold[Message[___], False]] := Null;
```

When you use `Quiet` the message expression form `Hold[_Message, False]` is producted, so `logMessage` is *expressly* omitting these messages from its collection.

---

To get all messages as you apparently want you can replace that definition:

```
EvaluationData[1]; (* preload - do not remove *)

CloudObject`Private`logMessage[bag_, Hold[Message[___], False]] =.;

self : CloudObject`Private`logMessage[_, Hold[_Message, False]] := 
  ReplacePart[Unevaluated@self, {2, -1} -> True]


Quiet @ EvaluationData[1/0]["MessagesExpressions"]
```

> ```
> {Hold[Message[Power::infy,1/0]]}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for investigation. Don't you think it should work like `Check` out of the box?

Comment: @Kuba Plainly the designer(s) thinks it should not or that definition would not have been included.  `Check` is a programmatic control and it makes sense to bypass the `Quiet` mechanism, as otherwise adding `Quiet` would break many programs using `Check`.  `EvaluationData` seems to just be a reporting function and I think it makes sense that `Quiet` has the effect that it does on it.  *Were it my choice it would be an option of EvaluationData*.

Comment: I see, well clearly it is another choice I find unexpected. If I wanted clean `EvaluationData` I'd have done `EvaluationData @ Quiet ...`. There is no notion of 'raporting function' but nevertheless `Check` would qualify there too. All that of course are subjective notes. God, isn't that obvious that there was a design choice that was not obvious and it should be emphasized in documentation? Why can't I predict the code I'm writing? Am I unable to learn WL or is L premature?

Comment: @Kuba I sympathize with your frustration.  Directorial emphasis seems to be on an ever-increasing number of functions with neither the development (performance) nor the documentation to support it.  *Mathematica* has become "bloatware."  It saddens me. :-(